# Assigned legend colors don't work/show

Tags: r, plot, colors, legend, kernel-density

I'm fairly new to R.
I'm trying to create a density plot, which wasn't problem thanks to previous questions & answers here.

My current problem is the graphs's legend. I've assigned the wanted colors (`col = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple")`) but they don't show on the legend itself, instead I get random colors.
I think it's important to mention that there are no errors after running the code & i've checked that all these colors are available [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf).

This the density plot code, along with the legend info.

```
plot(density(df$a1), col = "red", xlim = c(0, 1000), ylim = c(0, 0.004))
lines(density(df$a2), col = "orange")
lines(density(df$a3), col = "yellow")
lines(density(df$a4), col = "green")
lines(density(df$a5), col = "blue")
lines(density(df$a6), col = "purple")
legend(x = "topright", legend = names(df), fill = 1:6, col = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"))
```

Yet, the result is this:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`fill` specifies color for boxes while `col`specifies color for points and lines.

In your case, the code should be:

```
legend(x = "topright", legend = names(df), lty=1, col = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"))
```

`lty=1` indicates that you want solid lines in place of boxes (`lty` stands for **l**ine **ty**pe).